# C# get webpage data

Tags: c#, web

Can someone please help show me how to get the data from this website using C#:
https://fullmeter.com/fatonline/#/framedata/Guile

I would like to get the data in the table. I tried using webclient download string but I do not see the data in the string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not able to see it directly because when site loaded not all content has been loaded, and ajax call created to bring the data

Answer (score 1):

you are not able to see it directly because when site loaded not all content has been return,ajax call created to bring the data.

use webclient and call this page: https://fullmeter.com/fatonline/lib/characterData.json?ver=010102 you will get it as json sturcture

Comment: tyvm proxytype, could you please tell me how you were able to come up with that webpage?

Comment: very simple, follow chrome network console and see the XHR calls.

Comment: thank you again for you help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) class(in WinForms or WPF app, also there are ways to use it in Console app but they are somewhat [inconvenient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581)), which has `DocumentCompleted` or `LoadCompleted` event which should occur when page has finished loading.